# Repeated repeated sampling without replacement

Tags: python, pandas, random

I have a Slots dataframe with ~1,000,000 race+gender slots (so **efficiency is a slight concern**, I think). There are 3 race categories (White, Black, Hispanic) and 2 gender categories (Male, Female), for a total of 6 race-gender categories (e.g. White-Male (WM), Black-Female (BF), etc.). The dataframe is grouped into blocks of 10 slots that have different race+gender compositions (e.g. one may have 2 WMs, 2 BF, 3 HF, 1 HM, 1 WF, and 1 BM etc.), though there is always at least one of each. **The people in a given block have to be unique.**

Here's part of the Slots dataframe:

| Block | Race_Gender | Person Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | WM |  |
| a | WM |  |
| a | BF |  |
| a | HF |  |
| a | HM |  |
| a | HM |  |
| a | HM |  |
| a | HM |  |
| a | BM |  |
| a | WF |  |
| b | BM |  |
| b | BM |  |
| b | BM |  |
| b | HF |  |
| b | HM |  |
| b | WF |  |
| b | WF |  |
| b | BF |  |
| b | WM |  |
| b | WM |  |
| ... | ... | ... |

**I need to fill those race-gender slots using a population of 60 people**. The population of 60 is comprised of 10 people from each of the 6 race-genders. For simplicity, we'll name the people according to their race-gender, e.g. White Male1, ..., White Male10, Black Female1, ..., Black Female10, etc. The Population dataframe looks like this:

| Race_Gender | Person Name |
| --- | --- |
| WM | White Male1 |
| WM | White Male2 |
| ... | ... |
| WM | White Male10 |
| BF | Black Female1 |
| ... | ... |
| BF | Black Female10 |

I want to **randomly, without replacement**, fill the slots. Of course, there are more slots than people, but I want the "without replacement" piece to happen repeatedly until the people are used up. Specifically, once I use up all 10 people in a given race-gender category, I would re-populate with the original 10 and then repeat, as needed. Hence "repeated repeated sampling".

So the resulting dataframe would look like this (notice no repeats across blocks):

| Block | Race_Gender | Person Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | WM | White Male10 |
| a | WM | White Male4 |
| a | BF | Black Female2 |
| a | HF | Hispanic Female2 |
| a | HM | Hispanic Male3 |
| a | HM | Hispanic Male7 |
| a | HM | Hispanic Male6 |
| a | HM | Hispanic Male1 |
| a | BM | Black Male5 |
| a | WF | White Female7 |
| b | BM | Black Male1 |
| b | BM | Black Male3 |
| b | BM | Black Male10 |
| b | HF | Hispanic Female1 |
| b | HM | Hispanic Male5 |
| b | WF | White Female4 |
| b | WF | White Female3 |
| b | BF | Black Female1 |
| b | WM | White Male6 |
| b | WM | White Male7 |
| ... | ... | ... |

My two main ideas are:

1. Build a dataframe from the population of 60 so that it's big enough to cover the Slots dataframe. Then either sample all the people needed from each race-gender and merge them on. The problem, I think, is ensuring no duplicates within a block.
2. My current idea: Make a copy of the Population dataframe, then iterate (`itertuples()`,`df.values()`, or convert to dict and loop) over the Slots dataframe, randomly choosing an appropriate person from the Population and removing them from the copy. If there are no more from that subpopulation, then re-populate it with the originals from the Population dataframe. **The only problem is that this is running very slowly. Just 15,000 rows takes 30 seconds to populate!**

Any better ideas?

Here's the code for my current idea:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(0)

########################
#  FOR REPLICATION
########################
## GENERATE POPULATION DATAFRAME
def generate_pop():
    races = ["White","Black","Hispanic"]
    genders = ["Male","Female"]
    names = []
    race_genders = []
    for i in range(1,11):
        for r in races:
            for g in genders:
                names.append(f"{r} {g}{str(i)}")
                race_genders.append(r[0]+g[0])
    return pd.DataFrame({"Name":names,"Race_Gender":race_genders})

## GENERATE SLOTS DATAFRAME
def generate_slots():
    # Fixed parameters
    race_genders = ["BM","WM","HM","BF","WF","HF"]
    blockSize = 10

    # adjustable parameters
    numBlocksToGenerate = 1000

    # create as many blocks as is specified
    slots = []
    blockID = 1 # this identifies the blocks of 10
    for c in range(1,numBlocksToGenerate+1):
        # initialize block to have at least one of each race_gender, the block ID, and an empty name cell
        block = [(rg, blockID, "") for rg in race_genders]

        # keep adding randomly selected race-genders until the block is full
        while len(block) < blockSize:
            block.append((random.choice(race_genders),blockID))

        # add the block to the list of all blocks
        slots.extend(block)

        blockID += 1

    return pd.DataFrame(slots, columns=["Race_Gender","Block", "Name"])

popDF = generate_pop()
slotsDF = generate_slots()


###################
#   MAIN CODE
###################
# a dynamic copy of the Population of 60 people (with Name and Race_Gender columns). 
# It will grow and expand as people are randomly selected out and re-populated back in
popDF_dynamic = popDF.copy() 

# convert slots DF to dict for faster processing
slots_dict = slotsDF.to_dict('records')

def fill_slot(row):
    global popDF_dynamic
    # get the subset of people in the current race-gender category
    subpop = popDF_dynamic[popDF_dynamic["Race_Gender"] ==  row["Race_Gender"]]

    # if all people in the supop are used up, re-populate from the original
    if len(subpop) == 0:
        popDF_dynamic = pd.concat([popDF_dynamic, popDF[popDF["Race_Gender"] == row["Race_Gender"]]])
        subpop = popDF_dynamic[popDF_dynamic["Race_Gender"] ==  row["Race_Gender"]]

    # randomly select one
    choice = subpop.sample()

    # drop it from the dynamic Population dataframe
    popDF_dynamic.drop(choice.index, inplace=True)

    # add the person to the row
    row["Name"] = choice.iloc[0]["Name"]     

    return row   

# final dataframe
final = pd.DataFrame([fill_slot(row) for row in slots_dict])
```

Comment: Could be that I am missing some requirement of your question but  - what about shuffling your population DF and then just take from the top?  Since the population DF then will be in random order you are effectively doing random sampling without replacement.

Comment: How would you actually implement the "take from the top" part so that I'm putting a person in a correct race-gender slot? Also, is this different than simply `popDF.sample(1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

A much smarter friend of mine found an answer (code solution below). The key thing he explained to me is that the **bottleneck is storing things in memory**. For example, every time I went to fill a slot I created a subsetted dataframe (subpop). And every time I'd used up the people from a race-gender, I'd recreate `popDF_dynamic` with a `pd.concat()`.

His solution was to convert `popDF` into a dictionary of lists of people (`pop_dict`) in each race-gender, and then to create a "used" `set()` for each race-gender. Then we simply randomly select integers, representing the people in `pop_dict`, into `used`. Once all people from the race-gender have been "used", we `clear()` the set.

Here's his solution:

```
###################
#   MAIN CODE
###################
race_genders_list = ["BM","WM","HM","BF","WF","HF"]
# Create a dictionary of the people, where the key is the race-gender, and the values are a list of the people)
pop_dict = {rg: [x for x in popDF.to_dict('records') if x["Race_Gender"] == rg] for rg in race_genders_list}
   
# convert slots DF to dict for faster processing
slots_dict = slotsDF.to_dict('records')

# create another dictionary of race-genders, the values for which will be sets of integers representing selected people from pop_dict
used = {rg: set() for rg in race_genders_list}

# create a block-level version. This will be used to ensure people are unique in a block. So when all people of a given race-gender have been "used", we don't select one that was just used in that block 
used_in_block = {rg: set() for rg in race_genders_list}

# used to track if new block 
lastBlock = 0

def fill_slot(slot):
    srg = slot["Race_Gender"]

    # If new block, clear out the block's tracking sets
    global lastBlock
    if slot["Block"] != lastBlock:
        for rg in race_genders_list:
            used_in_block[rg].clear()
        lastBlock = slot["Block"]
            
    # if all people from the current race-gender have been used, clear the used set
    # but re-populate with whatever has been used in that block, to ensure uniqueness in the block    
    if len(used[srg]) == len(pop_dict[srg]):
        used[srg].clear()
        used[srg].update(used_in_block[srg])
           
    # randomly select from the list of unused people
    i = random.choice([x for x in range(len(pop_dict[srg])) if x not in used[srg]])
    
    # add selection to the used and used-in-block sets
    used[srg].add(i)
    used_in_block[srg].add(i)
    
    # get the selected person (at int i) from pop_dict
    choice = pop_dict[srg][i]
        
    slot["Name"] = choice["Name"]
    return slot

# final dataframe
final = pd.DataFrame([fill_slot(slot) for slot in slots_dict])
```

**This ran in about 0.1 seconds!**